# Reporting services + report parameters and custom dropdown length

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have some report and plenty of parameters inside that report. 
One of parameter contains values stored inside dropdown list (that are downloaded from db). 
Is there any way I can set the maximum length of that dropdown control? The problem is that when I expand drop down list I have a horizonal scrollbar because some values inside that dropdown list are too long. How can I customize this parameter and dropdown control so there will be no horizontal scrollbar and values inside it will always be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't using SSRS. The only way you could do it, would be to build a custom wrapper on top. By that I mean a little web app that collects your report parameters before calling the reports url & passing them all in on the URL.